# Why doesn't Hartshorne use Proposition II.5.6 to prove Theorem III.3.5?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Proposition II.5.6 of Hartshorne states that if $0\rightarrow F_1\rightarrow F_2\rightarrow F_3\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on an affine scheme $X$ with $F_1$ quasi-coherent, then the induced sequence of global sections is exact. It seems that Theorem III.3.5, which states that $H^i(X,F)=0$ for all $F$ quasicoherent on a noetherian affine scheme $X$ and $i>0$, follows almost immediately. For instance embed $F_1$ into an injective quasi-coherent sheaf $F_2$ and take the cokernel $F_3$ to get a short exact sequence. Then, taking the long exact sequence in cohomology implies that $H^1(X,F_1)=0$ and $H^i(X,F_3)=H^{i+1}(X,F_1)$. Induction implies the vanishing for all $i$ and all quasi-coherent sheaves. Why does Hartshorne cite EGA in Remark III.3.5.1 to prove this theorem in the non-Noetherian case? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why can you embed F into an injective quasi-coherent sheaf? Injective in the category of quasicoherent modules is not the same thing as injective in the category of all modules.

Comment: Just to add to user00000's comment -- Hartshorne proves in III.3.4 that on a Noetherian affine scheme, an injective module gives rise to a flasque sheaf (which is enough for this application) -- however his proof uses Noetherian induction.

Comment: You can extend the result that "injective QCoh(X)" implies "acyclic for sheaf cohomology" to, I think, quasi-compact semi-separated schemes.

Comment: But at least for noetherian schemes, tilde of an injective module is an injective quasicoherent sheaf, see e.g. Hartshorne exercise 3.6 (a).

Comment: That exercise says that the module is injective in qcoh(X), which as I said above doesn't necessarily imply injective in the bigger category O_X-Mod.